# Sorting JSONArray with empty string and in descending order

Tags: android, json, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

Hi please see problem before marking as duplicate

I have a jon array

```
[
{
"ID":"1324"
"iname":"Abc",
"icounts":"234",
"ilikes":"098"
},
{
"ID":"1224"
"iname":"bcd",
"icounts":"",    //icounts has empty value
"ilikes":"098"
},
{
"ID":"1367"
"iname":"Abc",
"icounts":"28",
"ilikes":"098"
},
{
"ID":"1098"
"iname":"Abc",
"icounts":"",
"ilikes":"098"
},
{
"ID":"1444"
"iname":"dfgbc",
"icounts":"222",
"ilikes":"098"
},
{
"ID":"1411"
"iname":"bwec",
"icounts":"444",
"ilikes":"9"
}

]
```

I have to sort it by "icount" value in Decreasing order

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList= ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>;
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(hres.getEntity()); // in jsonString i am storing json response 
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for (int i = 0 ; i <jarray.length();i++)
{
 JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
 HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
 map.put("ID", jobj.getString("ID"));

 map.put("iname", jobj.getString("iname"));
 map.put("icount", jobj.getString("icount"));
 map.put("ilikes", jobj.getString("ilikes"));
 arrayList.add(map);
 Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
  @Override
 public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs, HashMap<String, String> rhs) {
  return lhs.get("icounts").compareTo(rhs.get("icounts"));
  }
});
}
```

Due to the null fields the compareTo is not sorting properly on 
So i want to sort it in Descending order .
Suggestions please

Comment: I don't think you should use `HashMap`. You probably should create a class for your datas, with for fields. However the reponse from Raghu Rami Reddy seems good.

Answer (score 1):

Add a logic to check icount value and add value "0" if it is null or empty string. 
Example:

```
String icounts = jobj.getString("icount");
```

Check like this:

```
if(icounts!=null && icounts.trim().length() >0 )
{
map.put("icount", jobj.getString("icount"));
}
else{
map.put("icount", "0");
}
```

Hope this helps for you